# Replace numbers in strings with a placeholder using a given pattern

Tags: php, regex

I need to replace numbers with a placholder in my case %dx% where x is the number of the diferent numbers fuonded in the string number one.

I have two strings:

```
$a = "hello 3 33 4 3";
$b = "hello 33 3 4 3";
```

Taking the number of the string `$a`, I would like to replace the numbers in the string `$b`:

```
$a = "hello %d0% %d1% %d2% %d0%";
$b = "hello %d1% %d0% %d2% %d0%";
```

If the string number two have a number that don't exist in the string $a I don't need to do nothing, example:

```
$a = hello 123 you are the firts today;
$b = hello 123 you are the 1st today;
```

should output:

```
$a = hello %d0% you are the firts today;
$b = hello %d0% you are the 1st today;
```

At the moment I use a function like this:

```
$c = [];
$new = preg_replace_callback('/\d+/', function($matches) use (&$c) {
    if(false !== ($idx = array_search($matches[0], $c))) {
    return '%d'.$idx.'%';
    }
    else {
        $c[] = $matches[0];
        return '%d'.(count($c)-1).'%';
    }
}, $string); 
unset($c);
```

To replace all the numbers founded in the string, but I would like to pass by my self the pattern to find and match to preserve the original order.

At the moment I used a `preg_match_all`

```
  $pattern = '/\d+/';
  $cntRef = preg_match_all($pattern,$row[$lang],$numbers);
```

To get the number of the pattern matched, and the array of the numbers, after this I already check that the quantity of the numbers, and the numbers in the `preg_match` return array `($numbers)` are equals.

At the moment I don't know how to use the `$numbers` array as pattern to replace the numbers in the string `$b` keeping the same order of string `$a`

Some example:

```
$reference = "foo1 bar 2 45 foo7";
// $pattern recived is [1,2,45,7]
$b = "hello 7 2 i'm bar1 and 45";
//passing $b to my...ours function and $pattern shuold became:
// OUTPUT: "hello%d3% %d1% i'm bar%d0% and%d2%";

$reference = "foo 1 bar 1"
$b = "bar 1 baz 1"
//OUTPUT "bar %d0% baz %d0%"

$reference = "Everybod1 was Regex 23 fighting";
$b = "In my 23 years old i bougth 1 car";
//OUTPUT "In my %d1% years old i bougth %d0% car
```

The main problem I have, I don't kow how to pass the $pattern to my `preg_replace_callback` and use it inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

> The main problem I have, I don't kow how to pass the $pattern to my preg_replace_callback and use it inside of it.

You can use your pattern inside the `preg_replace_callback` callable parameter if you extract it to a variable and inherit the value from the parent scope, with the `use` keyword. Your code should look something like this:

```php
$pattern = '/\d+/';
$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($element) use ($pattern) {
    // You can use the $pattern variable here
}, $subject);
```

Comment: My mind is up to me, I already did it, but I forget the importance of the $c variable I used to "reset" at the beginnig...